# Why does instantiation work, while an equivalent static method does not?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, groovy

I'm working with some Elasticsearch integrations in Java/Groovy, and I've got a `BulkProcess` that I'm trying to add a `bulkSize` setting to.

Originally, I used this code:

```
package ...

import org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkProcessor
import org.elasticsearch.common.unit.ByteSizeValue

class ExampleClass {
  @Bean
  BulkProcessor buildBulkProcessor(@Value('${bulk.size:5}') long bulkSize) {
    BulkProcessor.builder(/* ... */)
    // ... (other settings)
    .setBulkSize(ByteSizeValue.ofMb(bulkSize))
    .build()
  }
}
```

*(This is a `.groovy` file, so no `;` line endings and implicit `return`)*

This code did not work, and triggered this error:

> No signature of method ByteSizeValue.ofMb() is applicable for argument types: (Long) values: [5]

*Side question, is `[5]` saying that `bulkSize`, which should be `5`, is actually an Array/List/Map/whatever of `5`? Or is that just how my output is displaying it?*

But, looking at the code, that seems to be exactly what is expected:

```java
public class ByteSizeValue implements Writeable, Comparable<ByteSizeValue>, ToXContentFragment {
  // ...

  public static ByteSizeValue ofMb(long size) {
    return new ByteSizeValue(size, ByteSizeUnit.MB);
  }
}
```

`ofMb()` is a public static method, that takes a `long` and returns a `ByteSizeValue` instance using the supplied value and `ByteSizeUnit.MB`. But, as you can see, this didn't work.

I changed the code to the following:

```
.setBulkSize(new ByteSizeValue(bulkSize, ByteSizeUnit.MB))
```

Which is pretty much exactly what `ByteSizeValue.ofMb(bulkSize)` is *supposed* to do, and my code functioned without triggering an exception, but I'm struggling to understand why.

I'm relatively new to Java/Groovy, coming from a PHP background, so it's possible my understanding of static methods is a little skewed by all of that, but hoping someone could shed some light on this scenario.

Comment: Your static method expects a primitive long but it is getting a java.lang.Long, the wrapper type. Thats how i interpret the error message, anyway. I dont know why the unboxing wouldnt work here.

Comment: Hmm interesting; yeah, `Long` vs `long` definitely could be the issue; nice catch. I tried a bunch of different approaches to cast `bulkSize` to a `long`, like `@Value('${bulk.size:5L}') long bulkSize` (came back as a `String`), and even `ByteSizeValue.ofMb(bulkSize as long)` (same error). There's probably some `Spring` magic (`@Bean`/`@Value`, etc.) going on with the configuration, and I'm cool going with the `new ...` approach. I'll keep digging though, and will post an update/answer if I find anything new. Thanks!

Comment: Does it fail in a simple standalone script? What versions of groovy/elastic?

Comment: @tim_yates I suspect it doesn't, but I don't actually have a simple way to test this code standalone (I might, but it's a new codebase to me, with tests spread over multiple projects). Elasticsearch version is `org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:7.12.1`, not sure about Groovy.

Comment: The following standalone script works with Groovy 4.0.18:

`@Grab('org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:7.12.1')                        `
`import org.elasticsearch.common.unit.ByteSizeValue                       `
`long bulkSize = 5                                                         `
`def result = ByteSizeValue.ofMb(bulkSize)                               `
`assert result instanceof ByteSizeValue                                      `
`assert result.size == 5                                                          `
`assert result.unit.toString() == 'MB`'